# How do I populate the database/model without using forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

How do I populate a model without using a form? If the following model is the example model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :project_name

    belongs_to :user

    validates :project_name, :presence => true
    validates :user_id,      :presence => true

end
```

Usually a form such as the following would be used:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :project_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But if I wanted to populate the model without using a form (say, if I wanted to do some internal calculations/manipulations in ruby and use output to populate the form), how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way of populating your models is by using seeds . http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data
Or you can make some rake tasks depending on what you want to do .

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply create a new Object of your Model and save it via. :entry.save